# Solving linear equation system using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 equations

```
-950 X = B1
-550 X = B2
-250 X = B3
```

B1, B2, B3 are known values 3D arrays

X should be also a 3D array

My code is

```
A = np.array([-950],[-550],[-250])
B = np.array([np.log(b1000_data/b50_data), np.log(b600_data/b50_data),     np.log(b300_data/b50_data)])
X = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
```

However, it fails

```
A = np.array([-950],[-550],[-250]) ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should be doing like:

```
a = np.array([[-950], [-550],[-250]])
```

Given your equation `Ax=B`. In this case you have more equations than required. This results in many possible `x` values. In this case `3`. It will result into error.

Read here: https://andreask.cs.illinois.edu/cs357-s15/public/demos/06-qr-applications/Solving%20Least-Squares%20Problems.html

Comment: Thanks, it seems my data set is very complicated for linear solving.